# Java, getting an ArrayList index by object

Tags: java, arraylist

so I have hit a little problem in my code I have:

```
synchronized(clients)
            clients.remove(this);
}
```

for when a client disconnects, but now I need to be able to send the name of that client to all the other clients, and to do this I essentialy need to do something like

```
synchronized(clients)
            broadcast("Remove:"+clients.get(this).name);
            clients.remove(this);
}
```

but obviously I can't get an index with the "this", so how do I go about getting the right clients name? Thanks!

Comment: i think you want to remove object from list. why do u need to get index.simply u cam use list.remove(object); or list.remove(inndex);

Answer (score 13, accepted):

why don't you simply use this.name?
As you already have the object why do you need to get the index to again get the object?

Edit:

To answer the question in the title(to get index of the object) use [indexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: You sir, are correct, I have to stop doing late night programming hahahah!

Answer (score 5):

Did you look at the [indexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29) function in ArrayList?

Answer (score 3):

```
int index = clients.indexOf(this);
// Do what ever...
clients.remove(index); // or clients.remove(this);
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you want to remove specific object from list. If you  get index from your code

```
int index = clients.get(this)
```

Then you can remove easily

```
clients.remove(index);
```

or if you get object from list then remove

```
clients.remove(object) // remove by object
```